# Apache Rewrite does not redirect

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm having an odd issue where, according to Javascript (in Chrome), all of the strings I tested match the Regex I have for a RewriteRule, but not all of them redirect properly.

My patterns are (in this order):

```
ups/sections/([A-Za-z]{3})/([A-Za-z0-9_+.-]+)$
ups/([A-Za-z_+.-]+)$
```

and the files I tested are:
(marked with + for a successful redirect, - for not)

```
+ ups/sections/clr/0085.jpg
- ups/closer2_alt.pdf
+ ups/moondance_ten.pdf
+ ups/connick_mlo.pdf
- ups/jackson5_ten.pdf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ups/([A-Za-z_+.-]+)$
```

should be

```
ups/([A-Za-z0-9_+.-]+)$
```

if you want all 5 to redirect.